# Firebase signIn not running

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to login to a firebase user through swift code. However, it seems like the code to do so is being completely skipped over. The callback is not being run at all. I have added the dependencies to my Podfile, ran `pod install`, and the modules show up in Xcode.

```
pod 'Firebase', '6.15.0'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

I `import Firebase` in my file. I also have tried including `import FirebaseAuth` as well but with no effect, likely because it is implicitly imported with Firebase. Here is the code where I sign in:

```swift
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: "fake@email.com", password: "fakepassword123") { (user, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    else if let user = user {
        print(user)
    }
}
```

However, again, this is seemingly just skipped over because the body of the callback is not being run. Shouldn't the callback run regardless, with either a result or an error? Any ideas? Thanks.

Edit: Also, if it helps, I at one point had a simple print statement at the start of the block to see if it was running and the print statement did not fire.

Comment: Please only use the `xcode` tag for questions about the XCode IDE itself. For questions about iOS programming in general, use the `ios` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: "fake@email.com", password: "fakepassword123") { (user, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    else {
        print(user)
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work let me know and we can keep troubleshooting, but this is exactly what I use and it works perfectly.

Comment: How is this different from the code OP already has in their question?

Comment: The "else if" is just changed to "else" that way we can assess whether the block simply isn't running or if the user field is for some reason equal to nil

Comment: Got it. Thanks for clarifying. You might want to add that explanation in your answer, or provide that suggestion in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. Unfortunately no change except a warning `Expression implicitly coerced from 'AuthDataResult?' to 'Any'` Edit: Also, if it helps, I at one point had a simple print statement at the start of the block to see if it was running and the print statement did not fire.

Comment: Weird... just to save a lot of unnecessary digging, you are calling the function that executes the code, right?

Comment: Yes, I did wonder that as well but I put a print statement immediately before and after this chunk of code to verify that the function is being run.

Comment: Did you connect the app to the database correctly? That seems to be the only candidate left at this point because the code is correct

Comment: Do you know how I can verify that? I run `FirebaseApp.configure()` with no error output. I have a GoogleService-Info.plist in the same folder

Comment: Edit: Just found something likely pretty important. When I put the code in the middle of the function, long before the function finishes, it gives an output. (Wasn't successful because the user wasn't created but it is working as intended) So now what I need to figure out is how to delay the end of the function executing so that the completion block can run. I'm not entirely sure why swift doesn't just allow the completion block to finish on another thread. I may be able to make it from here, but if you know how to do the above, let me know! And thanks for the help

Comment: Try putting the code that makes the call to sign in into its own function, and then call that function from within your original function